# Call script based on variable name

Tags: php

I have a parent function that is passed a variable called `$scriptName`.  Depending on what is stored in `$scriptName`, I want to call the corresponding script.

I have a file called childOneScript.php

If `$scriptName=="childOne"`, how do I call `childOneScript.php`?

Comment: How does `childOneScript.php` expect to be called? By file inclusion, or does it expect to be requested by the browser?

Comment: `require 'childOneScript.php'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the normal `require`

`require_once $scriptName . 'Script.php';`

Keep in mind however that if the script does not exist PHP will raise a fatal error, so you should be checking that the script does indeed exist.

```
/**
   Assumes that $name does not contain the PHP extension and
   this function works with relative paths.
   If the file does not exist, returns false, true otherwise
*/
function loadScript($name) {
    $name = $name . '.php';
    if (!file_exists($name) || !is_readable($name)) {
        // raise an error, throw an exception, return false, it's up to you
        return false;
    }
    require_once $name;
    return true;
}
$loaded = loadScript('childOneScript');
```

Alternatively you can use `include`, PHP will only raise a warning if it can't find the script.

There are a few **security concerns** with the above function. For example if the user is allowed to define the value of `$scriptName` an attacker could use it to read any file that is readable to the web server user.

Here is an alternative that limits the number of files that can be dynamically loaded to just the files that need be loaded in this manner.

```
class ScriptLoader {

    private static $whiteList = array(
        // these files must exist and be readable and should only include
        // the files that need to be loaded dynamically by your application
        '/path/to/script1.php' => 1,
        '/path/to/script2.php' => 1,
    );

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function load($name) {
        $name = $name . '.php';
        if (isset(self::$whiteList[$name])) {
            require_once $name;
            return true;
        }
        // the file is not allowed to be loaded dynamically
        return false;
    }
}

// You can call the static method like so.
ScriptLoader::load('/path/to/script1');     // returns true
ScriptLoader::load('/path/to/script2');     // returns true 
ScriptLoader::load('/some/other/phpfile');  // returns false
```

Comment: @MrPk sorry I rejected your edit and then saw why you made it. apologies.

Comment: I accepted this one because I need it to be dynamic. The other answers would work though, but in my case, I need the dynamic solution.

Comment: Be very aware of security problems. If you let users control the value of `$name` this could easily turn into leaks

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
if ($scriptName=="childOne"){
    require_once(childOneScript.php);
}
```

> The require_once statement will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.

*Readup:* [require_once() | PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the include statement inside the If condition.

```
if $scriptName == "childOne" {
     include childOneScript.php;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) methods in `PHP`

```
<?php
function loadScript($scriptName) {
  if ($scriptName=="childOne") {
    include("childOneScript.php");
  }
}
?>
```

Keep in mind though that the included script is included where you load it. So it's inside the `loadScript` function. That means you cannot access it's content outside its scope.